# Selenium Webdriver scripts failed to run thru jenkins when using an AutoIT.exe

Tags: jenkins, autoit

I have a script build using keywords for Selenium webdriver. This scripts has an autoIt.ext for a specific task of a file upload. Its working fine with Eclipse. However, when I schedule them using Jenkins, it fails at this step.

```
ControlFocus("Open", "", "Edit1")
```

ControlSetText("Open", "", "Edit1", "C:\XXX\xxx.jpg")
ControlClick("Open", "", "Button1")

```
    - The keyword:

public static void file_Upload(String vKeyword){

        new WebDriverWait(myDriver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@title='Choose a file to upload']")));
        myDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@title='Choose a file to upload']")).click();
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\XXX\xxx.exe");
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I also was facing the same issue but resolved it by uploading the .exe file directly onto git repo.
Try this and may be your luck!

Comment: Here is how I have fixed it. To this not so logical problem, I have added "Sleep(2000)" in the AutoIT code and voila, it worked. ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1","Drive:\Location\file.extn")
Sleep(2000)
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")